# Contracted Christoffel symbol

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

On page 3 of this document:

https://studentportalen.uu.se/uusp-filearea-tool/download.action?nodeId=1247106&toolAttachmentId=247022

it shows how to calculate the contracted Christoffel symbol by

\begin{align*} \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu \lambda} &= \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \rho}(\partial_{\mu}g_{\rho\lambda} + \partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\rho} - \partial_{\rho}g_{\mu\lambda}  ) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}(\partial^{\rho}g_{\rho\lambda} + g^{\mu \rho}\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\rho} - \partial^{\mu}g_{\mu\lambda}  ) \\ &=  \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu \rho}\partial_{\lambda}g_{\mu\rho} \end{align*}

Can someone kindly please help and explain what's happening in step $2$ and $3$? I just don't get it.

Comment: Nothing much is happening there. From line one to two $g^{\mu\rho}$ is pulled into the bracket and indices are raised. From step two to three the summation index in the first term is renamed to $\mu$ (or equivalently in the third to $\rho$). Then the first and last terms cancel. If that is not clear to you I would suggest reintroducing the suppressed sums explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor product in step 1 is expanded and the 3 terms in step 1 are transformed into 3 terms in step 2 according to these rules:
$$g^{\mu \rho}\partial_{\mu}g_{\rho\lambda} \to \partial^{\rho}g_{\rho\lambda} $$
and
$$ g^{\mu \rho}\partial_{\rho}g_{\mu\lambda}  \to  \partial^{\mu}g_{\mu\lambda}  $$

this is because you can contract the index of a derivative (only the left-most one, if there are 2 or more derivatives acting on a tensor), while the middle term (the second one) is left untouched.

The first and third term in step 2 are the same , once you see that they differ only in the dummy indices, so they cancel each other and in step 3 we are left only with the second term of step 2.